# Show exhaustive information for passed tests in pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

When a test fails, there's an output indicating the context of the test, e.g.

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
______________________________ Test.test_sum_even ______________________________

numbers = [2, 4, 6]

    @staticmethod
    def test_sum_even(numbers):
        assert sum(numbers) % 2 == 0
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_preprocessing.py:52: AssertionError
```

What if I want the same thing for passed tests as well? so that I can have a quick check on the parameters that get passed to the tests are correct?

I tried command line options line `--full-trace`, `-l`, `--tb long`, and `-rpP`, but none of them works.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want pytest to annotate every successful line of the code? You loose context pretty soon.

Comment: @phd well, PyCharm will handle that for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Executing pytest with the `--verbose` flag will cause it to list the fully qualified name of every test as it executes, e.g.,:

```
tests/dsl/test_ancestor.py::TestAncestor::test_finds_ancestor_nodes
tests/dsl/test_and.py::TestAnd::test_aliased_as_ampersand
tests/dsl/test_and.py::TestAnd::test_finds_all_nodes_in_both_expressions
tests/dsl/test_anywhere.py::TestAnywhere::test_finds_all_nodes_when_no_arguments_given_regardless_of_the_context
tests/dsl/test_anywhere.py::TestAnywhere::test_finds_multiple_kinds_of_nodes_regardless_of_the_context
tests/dsl/test_anywhere.py::TestAnywhere::test_finds_nodes_regardless_of_the_context
tests/dsl/test_axis.py::TestAxis::test_finds_nodes_given_the_xpath_axis
tests/dsl/test_axis.py::TestAxis::test_finds_nodes_given_the_xpath_axis_without_a_specific_tag
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, If you add `--color=yes` to it, the output will have ":PASSED" in green.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just asking for standard output from passed test cases, then you need to pass the `-s` option to `pytest` to prevent capturing of standard output.  More info about standard output suppression is available in the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html).

Comment: Not the standard output from the passed test cases, but the output from pytest as if the tests fail.

Answer (score 2):

`pytest` doesn't have this functionality. What it does is showing you the error from the exception when an assertion fails.

A workaround is to explicitly include the information you want to see from the passing tests by using python's [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module and then use the [caplog](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/logging.html) fixture from `pytest`.

For example one version of a `func.py` could be:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger('my-even-logger')


def is_even(numbers):
    res = sum(numbers) % 2 == 0
    if res is True:
        log.warning('Sum is Even')
    else:
        log.warning('Sum is Odd')

#... do stuff ...
```

and then a `test_func.py`:

```
import logging
import pytest
from func import is_even

@pytest.fixture
def my_list():
    numbers = [2, 4, 6]
    return numbers
 
def test_is_even(caplog, my_list):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG, logger='my-even-logger'):
        is_even(my_list)
    assert 'Even' in caplog.text
```

If you run `pytest -s test_even.py` and since the test passes, the logger shows you the following message:

`test_even.py WARNING:my-sum-logger:Sum is Even`

Comment: I had trouble seeing logs for INFO level. Adding `log_cli=true` in `pytest.ini` solved it. Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886088/7283201).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late answer, but since this is the top result in Google it is worth mentioning that using the `-v` option pytests shows all the tests run (one by line) showing the result of the test colored: passed/skipped/failed

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer from 2018 by Ian Lesperance. It says `--verbose` rather than `-v` but they're the same option, just short/long forms of it.

Answer (score -1):

simple solution

I just raised an exception at end of the test

```
def test_server_run():
    print("ok")
    assert True
    raise Exception()
```

Comment: This will just make `pytest` to print out the source code of the test file.