# pytest can't see logs from function being tested

Tags: python, logging, flask, pytest

I have a flask app like this

```
from flask import Flask
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def catch_all():
    logging.warning("I'm a warning")
    return "This is a REST API"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

When I run it, I see the WARNING in the logs

```
WARNING:root:I'm a warning
```

I then create a test, like this

```
import fulfillment

def test_index():
    fulfillment.app.testing = True
    client = fulfillment.app.test_client()

    r = client.get('/')
    assert r.status_code == 200
    assert 'This is a REST API' in r.data.decode('utf-8')
```

When I run the test using `pytest`, I can't see the log message from my function under test. I found [How can I see normal print output created during pytest run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405063/how-can-i-see-normal-print-output-created-during-pytest-run), which sounds similar, but the `pytest -s` option doesn't work and I think it's actually talking about output from the test function, not the function under test.

How can I see the logs from the function under test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html#incompatible-changes-in-pytest-3-4) may be the cause. Just create `pytest.ini` with settings.

```
[pytest]
log_cli=true
log_level=NOTSET
```

Works fine:

```
pytest test_my.py
# ...
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
fulfillment.py                  37 WARNING  I'm a warning
PASSED                                                                   [100%]

=========================== 1 passed in 0.09 seconds ===========================
```

Also you can set `log_format`, `log_date_format` and other options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems odd to move away from logging visibility as a feature...but I'm glad there's a way to see the logs from my tested function